# Setting jQuery UI attribute in element itself

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Well, my question might be trivial, nevertheless:

To set an **accordion to fit its content**, the [docs say this](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-header):

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({ heightStyle: "content" });
```

May I do this in the element itself? This is what I'd like to do:

```
<div id="accordion" style="heightStyle: 'content';" >
```

Comment: `style=""` = **CSS**, `style="heightStyle: 'content';"` != **CSS**

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this fact. I wonder, if there is another attribute. Which one?

Comment: there's none, I'm sorry, you can try with `height:100%;` (CSS)

Comment: Too bad. Imagined a data-preset="heightStyle: content;" or such element attribute.

Comment: if you sneak into the accordion code you might be able to extend it! this would be quite possible! (to use the data attribute you suggested) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  This not a style element, it is a jQuery parameter. The parameter allows the `jQuery accordian` library to behave in a certain way.

This is just some of the code that executes just simply changing the value:

```
if (heightStyle === "fill") {
    maxHeight = parent.height();
    this.element.siblings(":visible").each(function () {
        var elem = $(this),
            position = elem.css("position");

        if (position === "absolute" || position === "fixed") {
            return;
        }
        maxHeight -= elem.outerHeight(true);
    });

    this.headers.each(function () {
        maxHeight -= $(this).outerHeight(true);
    });

    this.headers.next()
        .each(function () {
        $(this).height(Math.max(0, maxHeight -
            $(this).innerHeight() + $(this).height()));
    })
        .css("overflow", "auto");
} else if (heightStyle === "auto") {
    maxHeight = 0;
    this.headers.next()
        .each(function () {
        maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).css("height", "").height());
    })
        .height(maxHeight);
}
```

Comment: No way? Do I really have to inject some JS?

Comment: Have you tried not entering anything?  `content` seems to be the default.

Comment: Hm, no. As far as I see, 'fill' is the default. At least my accordion fills the content to identical heights.